# Distribution of iOS in-house application that is developed under iOS Developer Enterprise Program

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

I am new to itunesConnect and iOS app development & distribution.
I have an application that is developed and tested using the provisioning certificates that are generated by using an account of **Account Type : In-House**. Now the application is ready to distribute.
But, I got stuck in distributing the application. Tried to upload in iTunesConnect, but some link says that iTunesConnect will not help to distribute in-house apps. What shall I do now to distribute the app.
I got stuck in this stage for the last 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't distribute apps on the App store with an **iOS Developer Enterprise Program** account (see the [Enterprise account FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)).

> **If I am enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, can I distribute my apps on the App Store?**
>
> No. The ability to distribute apps on the App Store is only available
>   to developers enrolled in the standard iOS Developer Program. The iOS
>   Developer Enterprise Program only allows you to distribute your apps
>   to employees or members of your organization through Ad Hoc
>   distribution.
>
> If your company is enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program
>   but would also like to distribute your app(s) to customers on the App
>   Store, you will need to enroll in the [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).

Only **iOS Developer Program** can create provisioning profiles which can be used to submit apps to the App store.

You should sign up for a **iOS Developer Program** account and then you will have the following option when creating a provisioning profile.

[image: iTunes distribution profile]

If you want to distribute your application (make sure you don't break the license agreement - [§2.6
**No Other Permitted Uses**](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/enterprise/ios_program_enterprise_agreement_20130610.pdf)) you should use the middle option when creating an IPA in Xcode.

[image: Xcode distribution method]

The offical Apple process for deployment and distribution can be found [here](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/deployment.html) ([This](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Deployment_Technical_Reference_EN_Feb14.pdf) is probably the better document to look at on that page).

Comment: Can i change Apple developer Enterprise Program to normal Apple developer Program (Organization) so that I can submit apps in Appstore.

Comment: @nOObiOS I'm not sure, you'd be best contacting Apple and asking them. If its a mistake then I can't see why not. Be aware though that all your current apps signed with that Enterprise distribution certificate might stop working.

Comment: I have not got any apps uploaded so far.

Comment: @nOObiOS good luck when you contact Apple! Leave a comment on how it goes :)